# (Open)VPN tunnel with /64 to small network

Tags: openvpn, ipv6

I have access to a VPS with a /64 IPv6 range.
I'd like to give IPv6 connectivity to a small office through this tunnel.
I have linux on the VPS and on a linux box on the network at this office.
I'm currently running a sixxt tunnel, but sixxt is closing down.

I only have the one /64, can I use that on both the VPS and the local network?

Comment: this should get you most of the way... https://www.jacobdevans.com/ipv6-openvpn-tunneling-with-asus-merlinwrt/

Comment: can you get a /60 on your VPS? Splitting /64s is bad but possible

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get an IPv6 address from your ISP then you could try using a tunnel from he.net. Take a look at their [tunnelbroker site](https://tunnelbroker.net/). This would be similar in principal to the setup you currently have with SixXS.

Comment: I need a dynamic, reachable address for the endpoint for using he.net.
Im on dynamic, carrier grade nat over 4G.

Comment: Seems a bit Heath Robinson to me.

Comment: @Lenne If you have 4G your mobile carrier should already be supplying IPv6 to you. But you may need a newer dongle to actually use it.

Comment: No, there are 3 available mobile carriers available, they all laugh or sigh when I'm asking for IPv6. I have an TP-link Archer MR200, which is ipv6-capable.